# javascript: weird behavior of == for strings

Tags: javascript, equals

This is my code:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/myURL",
    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
        // aler prints success, but msg != "success" ????
        if (msg == "success") {
           //my code
        } else {
           //other code
        }
     }
});
```

Something weired happens: the alert dialog prints success, but msg != "success". What am I missing?
My php method just returns "success" or "failure" based on some action.

Comment: Is it possible the output of `/myUrl` is returning success with leading or trailing white-space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this before conditionals:

```
msg= jQuery.trim(msg).toLowerCase();
```

Assuming by your code you're using JQuery

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (msg.trim().toLowerCase() == "success")
{...}
```

You may have to prototype a `trim` method if it's not supported cross-browser.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply, you can use === for the comparision. May be it useful.

Answer (score 0):

There might be white space around the text.

I can suggest that for a robust way to fix this, return data in a specific format such as [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Add

```
 dataType:'json'
```

to your $.ajax configuration, and have the PHP output

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('msg'=>'success'));
```

or `'msg'=>'failure'` for the other possibility, of course.

Then in the JS,

```
success: function(data){
    alert(data.msg);
    if (data.msg == "success") {
       //my code
    } else {
       //other code
    }
```